# Python inventory issue

Tags: python, string-formatting

Im making a text based game that is like a Minecraft RPG Type deal, just for fun. And I have a fully working inventory, except for one thing. For example, when you check your inventory, I want it to say, "Wood x2" 2 being the amount, if you have 2, or however many you have. So, I set self.wood(the wood item) to self.wood = "Wood x%s" % self.woodcount(Amount of wood you have). You can see the code here:

```
def cinventory(self):
    print(self.woodcount)
    self.wood = ("Wood x%s" % self.woodcount)
    print("---------------------------------")
    print("            Inventory            ")
    for x in self.inventory:
        print(x)
    print("---------------------------------")
```

The problem is, it prints Wood x0 even if you have more than that. It always prints zero. I even made it print the woodcount before it prints your inventory, and it displays the actual number just fine, but when its in the line of code I made, it doesn't work. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`%s` is the [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for strings. Try using `%d` (digit) for numbers.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
self.wood = "Wood x%s" % str(self.woodcount)
```

by converting your integer to a string first. Note that I removed the extraneous parentheses, as they're not needed.

Comment: @user3238885 what is the `type` of `self.woodcount`?

Comment: Actually, both `%s` and `%d` work for me in Python 2.7 and 3.4, so there must be something else going on...